# Issue with loadData() method of WebView

Tags: android

Till now i was using 
**webView.loadData(str,"texl/html","utf-8");**.

This works fine in 2.3 version of Android but no data is displayed in 4.0 version of Android.For 4.0 version, I had to use

**webExpContent.loadData(str,"text/html; charset=UTF-8",null);**

and it worked fine...Can anyone tell me the difference between these two.

Comment: What is “webExpContent”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe strict mode is blocking the possibility of showing **HTML** content on main thread. Try apliying this at the start of your main activity:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```